# javascript wait before executing next time of code

Tags: javascript, firebug

i have this code i'm running in firebug

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i = i+1) 
{
    console.log("hi "+i);
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        console.log("hi again "+i);
    }, 10000); 
}
```

what i'm trying to do is that in every iteration, it will output the first message, wait 10 seconds then output the second message before going though the next iteration

when i run it however, the first message it outputted 3 times before the second message it outputted even once, i am wondering how i can fix my code to wait before executing the next line of code, in this case, proceeding with the next iteration

Comment: @RafaEl just because i've been on Stackoverflow for more then 2 years doesn't mean i know either, if you look at the majority of my questions they've been PHP/MySQL based

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that the body of the loop runs to completion before any of the callbacks to `setTimeout` run.  Hence it will print all of the "hi" messages before any of the "hi again" ones.  In order to fix this you will need to schedule the "hi" messages to run after the "hi again" ones run.  For example

```
(function() { 
  var go = function(count) { 
    console.log("hi " + count);
    setTimeout(function() { 
      console.log("hi again " + count);
      if (count < 3) { 
        go(count + 1);
      }, 10000);
  };

  go(0);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call setTimeout, it says "keep doing what you are doing, but in X milliseconds do this too.  So you need to do something like:

```
function sayHi(i) {
    console.log("hi "+i);
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        console.log("hi again "+i);
        if (i < 3) sayHi(i+1);
    }, 10000);
}

sayHi(0);
```

Comment: I didn't, this is recursion, not a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can always write simple time-consuming function to help you with your task

```
function pauseScript(seconds) {
  var stop = Date.now() + seconds*1000;
  for (var i; stop >= Date.now(); i++){}
}
```

and call it when you want to "stop" your code for some time

```
for (var i=1; i<=10; i++) {
  pauseScript(10) // pause 10 seconds
  var d = new Date();
  console.log("pass #"+i+" [time now = "+d.toTimeString().substr(0,8)+']');
}
```

in console log you'll see something like this
[image]